# Rotate DataLabel by react-apexchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am making a bar graph with React-apexchart and I have seen the data label but I cannot find any property that helps me to rotate the type data label as the data that is in the image

[image]

exactly as it is below the label I need to do the same but with the dataLabel but I can't think of how to do it, to emphasize better, I need that the numbers with percentage of the image look like the names of the first image

[image]

this would be the code of the graph: https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-data-labels/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with

```
  plotOptions:
    bar:
      dataLabels:
        orientation: vertical
```

See:
https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar/#orientation
and
https://apexcharts.com/docs/datalabels/